# Laravel 5.6 how to read text file line by line

Tags: php, laravel, file

Without Laravel I can use simple code to read text file by line:

```
$file = fopen("whatever/file.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

while(!feof($file)) {
   echo fgets($file). "<br>";
}

fclose($file);
```

With Laravel this simple thing becomes overwhelming due to local file storage location.

I.e. I can get file contents with `Storage::get('whatever/file.txt')` method, but how to get just a file and then read it in a loop?

I've tried to use `File::get('whatever/file.txt')` method but get an error: `File does not exist at path`.

How to read file from local storage (not public) line by line with Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $files = ExamFile::where('exam',$code)->get();
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $content = fopen(Storage::path($file->url),'r');

        while(!feof($content)){

            $line = fgets($content);

            echo $line."<br>";
        }

        fclose($content);
    }
```

You can use it like this. It works for me.

Answer (score 11):

You can get your file like this:

```
$file = fopen(storage_path("whatever/file.txt"), "r");
```

This will result in a path similar to this 
`'/var/www/storage/whatever/file.txt'` or `'/var/www/foo/storage/whatever/file.txt'` if you are serving multiple websites from the same server, it will depend on your setup, but you get the gist of it. Then you can read your file;

```
while(!feof($file)) {
    echo fgets($file). "<br>";
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: `storage_path` returns incorrect path destination.. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53008932/5246900)

Comment: i think this might be old but check this out https://josephsilber.com/posts/2020/07/29/lazy-collections-in-laravel

Answer (score 6):

Laravel v 10.10 Confirmed working!!

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::lines(storage_path('app/whatever.txt'))->each(function ($line) {
   $this->info($line);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to know where your file lives. You also need a path to get there.
E.g., if your file is located in the storage folder, you could do

```
File::get(storage_path('whatever/test.txt'));
dd($contents);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. `$file = Storage::get("whatever/test.txt");` works well for getting file content but `$file = File::get(storage_path('whatever/test.txt'));` returns an error: `File does not exist at path `

Comment: @mr.boris you have to check you file path

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help

```
  File::get(storage_path('whatever/file.txt'));
```

Answer (score 1):

So confusing!

My file was in the folder `storage/app/whatever/file.txt` but Laravel `storage("whatever/file.txt")` method recognizes it as `storage/whatever/file.txt` path.

As I said before it is overwhelming and confusing a lot.

So, `fopen('storage/app/whatever/file.txt')` works for me.

Comment: You could have used `storage_path('app/whatever/file.text')` instead.